# MulticlassClassificationEvaluator and Random forest

Tags: apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

Am running into an issue with `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` for random forest in logistic regression `trained_model.summary()` works on the `model.fit` but for some unknown to me reason with random forest it's returning just a float instead of a dictionary with each label and f1 score for the multilabel problem.